# PHP convert array entries

Tags: php

Hi I have such question.
I have a php array with 4 entries. And I need to create a CLASS task with them.

```
$array=array('USER','username','other','test');
```

This I want to use to generate this

```
    $array[0]::find_by_$array[1]($array[3]); 

it must look as    
    USER::find_by_username(test);
```

How I can convert the array values into this line ?
What is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array(array($array[0],'find_by_'.$array[1]),$array[3])
```

But this isn't the cleanest way to manage your code, there's no validation that the class or method exists, so subject to potential failure

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call_user_func_array` to call a [callback](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) with an array as parameters:

```
$callback = array($array[0], 'find_by_'.$array[1]);
$params = array($array[3]);

$ret = call_user_func_array($callback, $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array(array($array[0], 'find_by_'.$array[1]), $array[3]);
```